# Can I use the rpois to produce the random number under the different mean

Tags: r

I want to write a function to do some calculate. And in this function I want to use the rpois to produce the random number `y1` under the different mean `n1*2.4`. I find this function cannot get my aim, so I want to know how I should edit my function.

```
myfunC1 <- function(t1) {
    t1 = seq(1, 3000, 1)
    n1 <- 13.8065 / (1 + exp(-(t1 - 11.8532) / 26.4037))
    y1 <- rpois(1, n1 * 2.4)
    c <- log(2.7 / 2.4) * (y1 / n1 - (2.7 - 2.4) / (log(2.7) - log(2.4)))
    result <- c
}
```

And I also want to know how I should write a function to calculate the following statement without using the `for` loop. The y and Lt is already known in this statement.

G[t]=max{0,0.85*G[t−1]+L[t]}

Comment: Please give the expected and actual output of the function

Comment: For example, L[1:5]=(1,2,3,4,5)，and G[0]=0, so the G[1]=max(0,0.85*G[0]+1)=1,G[2]=max(0,0.85*G[1]+2)=2.85,G[3]=5.4225,G[4]=8.609125,G[5]=12.31775625. But I don't want to use the for loop to calculate this function.

Answer (score 0):

Your function with some change:

```
myfunC1<-function(t1) {
  n1<-13.8065/(1+exp(-(t1-11.8532)/26.4037))
  y1<-unlist(lapply(n1*2.4, rpois, n=1))
  c<-log(2.7/2.4)*(y1/n1-(2.7-2.4)/(log(2.7)-log(2.4)))
  return(c)
}
```

Your output:

```
    t1<-seq(1,10,1)
    myfunC1(t1)
 [1] -0.043210706  0.076575495  0.006905820 -0.139863770 -0.045328088  0.006866088 -0.037032547 -0.079171724
 [9] -0.083574188  0.018280450
```

About the second part of your question, you can use an approach like this one:

```
L<-runif(10,1,10)
G<-runif(10,1,10)

myfunC2<-function(G,L,t)
{
  return(max(0,0.85*G[t−1]+L[t]))
}

unlist(lapply(rep(1:length(L)),myfunC2, G=G, L=L))
 [1]  0.000000 14.094739  7.489582 14.268056 16.318365  9.115776 11.729936  7.091494 16.030881  9.289892
```

Comment: What is `t` for? It is never used.

Comment: This is a good point, it was already present in the original code. I will remove it in the answer's code.

Comment: Sorry， the ‘t’ is ‘t1’ in fact, in order to calculate the ‘n1’、‘y1’ and  ‘c’

Comment: Ok @jackray, Answer changed according to this

Comment: However, you can see the y1 is just a single number in fact , and I want to use the rpois to produce the random number y1 under the different mean n1*2.4. So y1 should be a vector.

Comment: Function changed using lapply in y1 calculation

Comment: I want to know if I write to this  y1<-rpois(3000,n1*2.4).   Can I get the same answer?

Comment: Using lapply every value in n1 is passed to rpois and the output stored in a list in y1

Comment: Using lapply I am sure that each n1 values is passed to rpois and used 1 time as lamba, using rpois you have to look inside its code to understand how it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would you like to see my following question?     I also want to know how I should write a function to calculate the following statement without using the for loop. The y and Lt is already known in this statement.

G[t]=max{0,0.85*G[t−1]+L[t]}

Comment: Added a possible way

Comment: myfunC2<-function(n1,h1){
  r=0
  i=0
  for (x in n1){
    b<-max(0,x+0.85*r)
    r=b
    if(r>h1) break
    i<-i+1
  }
  return(i)
}